# how i can get the whole objected from the selected row in datagridview without displaying the object ID -c#

Tags: c#, object, datagridview, selected

i have dgv and i bound it like this dgviewOrders.DataSource = Orders
but i would like to display objects without thier ID and when i select a row i want to get the whole object because this is what my teacher asked me to do but i couldnt do it

```
//i tried this code: 
var _bind = from a in Orders
            select new   OrderItem
            {
                ItemName = a.ItemName,
                Amount = a.Amount,
                Comment = a.Comment,
                Status = a.Status,
                TableNumber = a.TableNumber,
                Ordertime = a.Ordertime,
                Id = a.Id
            };
//dgviewOrders.DataSource = _bind.ToList(); 
dgviewOrders.DataSource = Orders;
```

and this is how i get the selected object :
 OrderItem currentObject = (OrderItem)row.DataBoundItem;
but when i comment the Id in the orders the object is empty

Answer (score 0):

DataGridView has `AutogenerateColumns` set to `true` by default. This means it will fill the `dgViewOrders.Columns` collection with DataColumn objects when bound to a data source

You have two choices for not displaying a column:

- set `autogeneratecolumns` to false, and fill the column collection yourself manually, and don't include the column you do not want to see
- leave `autogeneratecolumns` as true, and after you have bound your object and the columns have been generated, hide the one you don't want (`dgViewOrders.Columns["Id"].Visible = false;)

[This MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-hide-columns-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control) has some more info, but is essentially that line of code above

---

> when i select a row i want to get the whole object

To retrieve the currently selected data bound item for a row you have a couple of choices:

```
datagridview.CurrentRow
```

This returns you a reference to the datagridviewrow that contains the current cell. The current cell is the one with the faint outline around it that would receive the keyboard focus if you started typing. It can be moved with the cursor and is NOT necessarily a selected row

```
datagridview.SelectedRows
```

Returns you a collection of datagridviewrows that have been selected (turned blue) with the mouse, or by holding shift and moving the current row with the cursor keys. If your DGV is in single row select mode the collection will have only one row. Your DGV's `selectionmode` property MUST be `fullrowselect` or `rowheaderselect` - if it is set to anything else then the collection will not be populated

Whichever one of the above you choose, you will get one or more `DataGridViewRow` objects. They will have a `.DataBoundItem` property that, if your datasource is a DataTable, will probably be a DataRowView. That in turn will have a `.Row` property that is your datarow. This will either be a strongly typed (YourXyzNameHereDataRow) or a weakly typed (DataRow)

Hence if youre using datatables, your code will look something like:

```
'generic datatable
Dim dr as DataRow = DirectCast(DirectCast(dgViewOrders.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem, DataRowView).Row, DataRow)
'strongly typed datatable
Dim dr as OrdersDataRow = DirectCast(DirectCast(dgViewOrders.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem, DataRowView).Row, OrdersDataRow)
```

If youre not using datatables then it'll be something else in DataBoundItem; use the debugger to inspect